# Are there now 64-bit processors that deal with denorms routinely with no exception or interrupt?

Tags: floating-point

Title says it all.

Are there processors with FPUs that deal with denorms arithmetically correctly (don't assume they're zero nor flush them to zero) and don't cause an exception? I would be interested in knowing who the black sheep and the white sheep are. Like the Intel Xeon or AMD Opteron, are denorms for them just any old 64-bit floating-point number?

My app interest is about real-time digital signal processing.

Comment: The reply here by Peter Cordes seems to cover it well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60969892/performance-penalty-denormalized-numbers-versus-branch-mis-predictions

Comment: Tempted to close if that SO post that Knut links to answers.

Comment: Fine with me....